# How necessary/useful is const-correctness in C

Tags: c, constants, const-correctness

I'm in the process of learning both C and Assembly, and would like to figure out the connection between const-correctness and actual generated code.

My question is, given this function I have below, how do I give the compiler the maximum possible number of hints so that it generates the most efficient code.

```
void hdlc_tx_frame(const void* const buffer, uint8_t bytes_to_send)
{
    uint8_t data;
    uint8_t* tmp_buffer = buffer;

    // Start marker
    data = HDLC_FLAG_SEQUENCE;
    hdlc_tx_byte(&data);

    // Send escaped data
    while(bytes_to_send)
    {
        // Get next data
        data = *(tmp_buffer++);

        // See if data should be escaped
        if((data == HDLC_CONTROL_ESCAPE) || (data == HDLC_FLAG_SEQUENCE))
        {
            uint8_t tmp = HDLC_CONTROL_ESCAPE;
            hdlc_tx_byte(&tmp);
            data ^= HDLC_ESCAPE_BIT;
        }

        // Send data
        hdlc_tx_byte(&data);

        // decrement counter
        bytes_to_send--;
    }

    // End marker
    data = HDLC_FLAG_SEQUENCE;
    hdlc_tx_byte(&data);
}
```

Note that `hdlc_tx_byte(&data)` doesn't modify `data` in any way.

Is declaring `buffer` as a const pointer to const, and then going to the effort of creating a `tmp_buffer` variable any better than just leaving `buffer` as simply a pointer to const?

Is declaring that it's a pointer to const actually useful in any way either?

Does declaring bytes_to_send as non-const simply create a local copy for the function, and is this better form than calling it const and creating another temporary counter variable?

My apologies if this question is too general. Every time I do a search for this kind of thing elsewhere, I find sites telling me the possibilities of the syntax but nothing deeper than that.

Comment: Commenting on the title question, Incredibly useful. The self-imposed restrictions placed on the engineer to ensure both code and *concept* (I shouldn't need to modify this, so I'll make sure I *can't*) is beyond-valuable. Add to that the wealth of optimizations that can be done by modern compilers, especially when it is known by design something is immutable, and it is a *very* powerful mechanic.

Comment: And note: `uint8_t* tmp_buffer = buffer;` is not valid with your current declaration (not sure if you knew that, but your compiler will certainly tell you.) `const uint8_t* tmp_buffer = buffer;` is what I think you were going for. If your question is more about whether the *last* `const` in `const void * const buffer` is even needed, or whether there is any benefit in your design, no.

Comment: My compiler seems fine with that declaration, and doesn't seem to be generating a warning about casting away the constness. Then again, I'm using XC8 as my compiler (for PIC microchips).

For now I'm going to leave the last const out from the buffer declaration. I think with the way the compiler works, I'm placing an arbitrary limit on that which I'm then using a work around for anyway.

Comment: Placing a `const` qualifier on by-value parameters is rarely useful.